# Is it possible to read external smart contract data with smartpy

Tags: smartpy

I would like to make a smart contract (A) where I call an entrypoint on contract B

Is it possible to either check the return value of the entrypoint interaction or read a big_map of B's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read other contract's data directly.

Currently, Tezos only supports a callback pattern.
You can send a callback to another contract, and then the contract calls you back with a response.

This template should give you an idea: https://smartpy.io/ide?template=collatz.py

Only next proposal (Hangzhou) will allow synchronous calls (on-chain views): https://smartpy.io/docs/experimental/onchain_views

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to either check the return value of the entrypoint interaction or read a big_map of B's

You cannot do that both on-chain and without the collaboration of contract B.

Can you please explain in more details your scenario? If you don't trust contract B you should probably not interact with it.

Comment: @craftoyster34 Do you have a directauth id we could use to award you ( in Tezos ) for asking this question?

A twitter/gmail account would work as well.